# How to add match result to filter

Tags: jquery

I am looking for help. Hello everyone. I'd like to add some match result div. 
What I mean is:

When I filter elements by marking/unmarking checkboxes I would like to have a number of filtered offers displayed. For example, if the checkbox filter is giving 2 results I would like to see some sentence displayed. "We found 2 results."

When filtering will not giving any results then I would like to see information: "No results found."

Here is jsfiddle example of this filter: https://jsfiddle.net/q67oLwbd/2/

```
<div class="tabela-wrap">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="fl-1" value="1" id="1" /> 1</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="fl-2" value="2" id="2" /> 2</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="fl-3" value="3" id="3" /> 3</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="fl-4" value="4" id="4" /> 4</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="fl-5" value="5" id="5" /> 5</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="fl-6" value="6" id="6" /> 6</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="fl-7" value="7" id="7" /> 7</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="fl-8" value="8" id="8" /> 8</label>
</div>

<br><br>

<ul class="tabela">
  <li class="tabelki" data-id="" data-category="1 2 3 4 ">1 2 3 4</li>
  <li class="tabelki" data-id="" data-category="2 3">2 3</li>
  <li class="tabelki" data-id="" data-category="4 5">4 5</li>
  <li class="tabelki" data-id="" data-category="5 6 ">5 6</li>
  <li class="tabelki" data-id="" data-category="5">5</li>
  <li class="tabelki" data-id="" data-category="1 2">1 2</li>
  <li class="tabelki" data-id="" data-category="1 2 3">1 2 3</li>
  <li class="tabelki" data-id="" data-category="7 8">7 8</li>

</ul>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you edit your question and hit `Ctrl+M` or the `<>` icon, it will bring up the onsite snippet creator where you can make a working example of the issue, rather than linking to an offsite snippet site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I included the result count like you asked but decided to refactor your code to help DRY things up and make the code easier to read/understand. This reduces your 220 lines of JS to 47 and provides caching on your jQuery selectors.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // cache ref to all checkbox elements
  var checkboxes = $('input:checkbox'),
      // cache ref to results
      results = $('#results'),
      // cache ref to our list
      listItems = $('.tabela > li'),
      // collection of selected checkbox elements
      selectedItems = [];
  
  checkboxes.on('change', function(){
    var id = this.id;
    
    if(this.checked){
      // push the element vs the value
      selectedItems.push(this.value);
    }else{
      // remove items on uncheck
      selectedItems.splice(selectedItems.indexOf(this.value), 1);
    }

    updateList();
  });

  var updateList = function(){
    // ref all checked checboxes
    var checked = $('input:checkbox:checked'),
        // create map of values for joining
        selectedItemsValues = selectedItems.sort().join(' ');

    if(checked.length){
      // filter list items         
      listItems.hide().filter(function(){
        return this.dataset.category.includes(selectedItemsValues); 
      }).show();
        
      // count visible li only
      var total = $('.tabela li:visible').length;
      // render results
      results.html('We found ' + total + (total === 1 ? ' match' : ' matches' ) + '!');
    }else{
      listItems.show();
      
      results.html('We did not find any matches.');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tabela-wrap">   
  <label for="1"><input type="checkbox" name="fl-1" value="1" id="1" /> 1</label>
  <label for="2"><input type="checkbox" name="fl-2" value="2" id="2" /> 2</label>
  <label for="3"><input type="checkbox" name="fl-3" value="3" id="3" /> 3</label>
  <label for="4"><input type="checkbox" name="fl-4" value="4" id="4" /> 4</label>
  <label for="5"><input type="checkbox" name="fl-5" value="5" id="5" /> 5</label>
  <label for="6"><input type="checkbox" name="fl-6" value="6" id="6" /> 6</label>
  <label for="7"><input type="checkbox" name="fl-7" value="7" id="7" /> 7</label>
  <label for="8"><input type="checkbox" name="fl-8" value="8" id="8" /> 8</label> 
</div>

<br><br>

<ul class="tabela">
  <li class="tabelki" data-id="" data-category="1 2 3 4">1 2 3 4</li>
  <li class="tabelki" data-id="" data-category="2 3">2 3</li>
  <li class="tabelki" data-id="" data-category="4 5">4 5</li>
  <li class="tabelki" data-id="" data-category="5 6 ">5 6</li>
  <li class="tabelki" data-id="" data-category="5">5</li>
  <li class="tabelki" data-id="" data-category="1 2">1 2</li>
  <li class="tabelki" data-id="" data-category="1 2 3">1 2 3</li>
  <li class="tabelki" data-id="" data-category="7 8">7 8</li>
</ul>

<div id="results"></div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gjJzMp?editors=1010)

Comment: Nice. But if I press 5,6,7 there's should not be any result. I want only see elements with 5,6,7

Comment: oh, I thought you were filtering the list based on the selected number

Comment: Updated: I modified the answer to match the requested logic

Comment: I was able to get it down to 47 lines with the correct logic. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Great. So maybe you could know answer for this problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51880678/how-to-put-slider-together-with-additional-checkbox-filter I need use those checkboxes with UI slider to filter offers will your revsion work with slider i built?

Comment: Can you please help me with following problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51992696/uislider-buttons-doesnt-work-with-checkbox-filter